# Can't select from a SQL datasource "Cannot convert type 'NorthwindDataContext' to 'System.Idisposable'

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a SQL server datasource. This is probably really trivial but I can't see what I am missing.

My code so far is

```
    public List<string> GetCountries()
    {
        using (var context = new NorthwindDataContext())
        {
            return (from c in context.Customers
                select c.Country).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
```

But visual studio is complaining with

> "Cannot convert type 'NorthwindDataContext' to 'System.Idisposable'"

with regard to

```
new NorthwindDataContext()
```

it also can't seem to resolve

```
select c.Country
```

I'm using .net 4.5

can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is presumably because `NorthwindDataContext()` does not implement the `IDisposable` interface so you can't use it within a `using()` statement.

Try this instead:

```
public List<string> GetCountries()
{
    var context = new NorthwindDataContext();

    return (from c in context.Customers
           select c.Country).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks! but it still can't resolve the 'select c.Country'

Comment: What do you mean by `resolve`? What is in the list after the query is run? Is the `Country` a string type? Does the context actually have any `Customers`?

Comment: Within the database there is a Customers table, and within the customers table there is a Country column. on hovering over select, I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'Select'"

Comment: Does the database contain any customers? What is the country datatype? The query should work fine. Perhaps your context isn't set up correctly? This is probably another question entirely though..

Comment: Yep, I've checked the DB and can the table with all the columns I am expecting, country is string. I think you may be right about it being a different question, I'll create a new one.

Comment: I've put context.Customers in brackets, and that seems to have resolve the issue with select not resolving. I have no idea, why that worked though! Country still isn't resolving :(

Comment: Awesome, glad it's working. If this helped, please consider accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statement is tied to the `IDisposable` interface, as explained in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

> Provides a convenient syntax that ensures the correct use of
>   IDisposable objects.

This means that, after returning the list of your objects, the application will try to dispose the used objects and marking them for garbage collection. What your `using` will do corresponds to the following code:

```
try
{
    string s = myObject.Stuff();
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)myObject).Dispose();
}
```

Most probably, your `NorthwindDataContext()` object doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface and then you have a cast error. You cannot use the `using` statement.